# How to call docker run from c# application

Tags: c#, wpf, docker

I've got a WPF application that whilst processing a file needs to use a docker process. The docker container is built on the box, currently after processing a file with the WPF application the user has to start a command prompt and type in

```
docker run --it --rm -v folderdedirect process parameters_including_filePath
```

to do further processing.

I want to include that in the WPF application. I could presumably use `system.diagnostics.process` with `cmd.exe`?  I looked at the `Docker.dotnet` but couldn't for the life of me work out how it's supposed to just run a local container.

Comment: May be it helps https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's how I did it in the end but there may be a better way.

```
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("docker", $"run -it --rm blahblahblah");

processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

int exitCode;
using (var process = new Process())
{
    process.StartInfo = processInfo;
    process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(logOrWhatever());
    process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(logOrWhatever());

    process.Start();
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.BeginErrorReadLine();
    process.WaitForExit(1200000);
    if (!process.HasExited)
    {
        process.Kill();
    }

    exitCode = process.ExitCode;
    process.Close();
}
```

Comment: I am getting the System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'Access is denied'
error. Please help me.

Comment: process.Close(); is redundant since it is in a using() clause.

Answer (score -1):

Adapted the code above for my context. The hardest part is determining how you want to monitor if your process finished. You can try setting up event listeners as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.exited?view=netcore-3.1#:%7E:text=This%20occurrence%20means%20either%20that,the%20EnableRaisingEvents%20property%20is%20true%20.&text=Synchronous%20notification%20means%20calling%20the,thread%20until%20the%20process%20exits.). Having other conditions to verify (if client sends a kill signal), I decided to just continually monitor process.HasExited value.

```
private static void RunDockerImage(ContainerData containerData)
    {
        var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("docker", $"run "+containerData.ImageName);

        processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

        int exitCode;
        using (var process = new Process())
        {
            process.StartInfo = processInfo;

            // indicate process is started
            StartUpdateOrch(containerData);

            process.Start();
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            process.BeginErrorReadLine();

            while(!process.HasExited)
            {
                // continually check if kill signal is set
                if (getKillSignal())
                {
                    process.Kill();
                } 
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }

            exitCode = process.ExitCode;
            containerData.exitCode = exitCode;

            // indicate process is done
            FinishUpdateOrch(containerData);

            process.Close();
        }
    }
```